# Vectorized computation of returns from positions and bid-ask series

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, quantitative-finance

I have two series (`bids` and `asks`), and a list of positions. All have shape `(T, S)`.

In my example below, I have `T=5` timesteps and `S=3` symbols.

The `positions` represent a portfolio allocation for each symbol at each timestep. For example, if I have 5% of asset 1, 10% of asset 2 and 85% of asset 3 at timestep 4, then `positions[4]` is `[0.05, 0.1, 0.85]`.

When buying (an asset from `t` to `t+1` increases), the `ask` prices should be used. When selling, the `bid` prices should be used. This is because I am assuming a strategy where I only buy/sell with market orders, so I need to "cross the spread" each time.

How can I compute my returns given a list of positions over time, bid prices and ask prices?

For simplicity, all prices are quoted by the first asset (which price is always 1), and the starting position is `[1, 0, 0]`.

What I would like is a vectorized implementation of the `compute_returns_loop()` function (getting rid of the `for`-loop over timesteps).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T,S=5,3

asks = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1], [3, 3, 3.5, 4, 4], [13, 13, 15, 17, 21]]).T # (T, S)
bids = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1], [1, 1, 2.5, 2, 3], [11, 11, 13, 15, 19]]).T # (T, S)

positions_test_1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1,   0, 0  ], [1,   0, 0  ], [1, 0, 0]]) # (T, S)
positions_test_2 = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0,   0, 1  ], [0,   0, 1  ], [1, 0, 0]]) # (T, S)
positions_test_3 = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0.5, 0, 0.5], [0.5, 0, 0.5], [1, 0, 0]]) # (T, S)
positions_test_4 = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0,   0, 1  ], [1,   0, 0  ], [1, 0, 0]]) # (T, S)

# Quick visualization
plt.plot(asks[:, 2])
plt.plot(bids[:, 2])

# Here absolute means in the currency of the respective asset
# positions are expressed as ratio of the total portfolio allocation
def compute_returns_loop(positions, asks, bids):
    mids = (asks + bids) / 2

    current_absolute_position = positions[0].astype(np.float)
    for t in range(1, asks.shape[0]):
        unrealized_worth = (mids[t] * current_absolute_position).sum()
        target_absolute_position = positions[t] / mids[t] * unrealized_worth
        absolute_transactions = target_absolute_position - current_absolute_position
        current_absolute_position[1:] += absolute_transactions[1:]
        cost = np.where(absolute_transactions[1:] > 0, asks[t, 1:], bids[t, 1:])
        current_absolute_position[0] -= (cost * absolute_transactions[1:]).sum()
    return current_absolute_position[0]

def compute_returns_vectorized(positions, asks, bids):
    mids = (asks + bids) / 2
    # TODO
    return None

print(compute_returns_loop(positions_test_1, asks, bids)) # should be  1
print(compute_returns_loop(positions_test_2, asks, bids)) # should be ~1.2
print(compute_returns_loop(positions_test_3, asks, bids)) # should be ~1.1
print(compute_returns_loop(positions_test_4, asks, bids)) # should be  1

# replacing compute_returns_loop with compute_returns_vectorized should give approximately the same results
```

Comment: Though it may be possible to vectorize this loop, it's worth asking what the end goal is. If it's just hitting a certain latency or speed requirement, you may want to consider Numba, particularly if this is just a small representation of larger data. You'll want to avoid the in-place operations and instead allocate a new memory buffer, though.

Comment: @NickBecker The goal is to run some gradient-based stochastic optimization in pytorch. I checked that it is possible to loop over T and still backpropagate in pytorch, but it's much slower as expected.

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier Could you explain the logic of the `compute_returns_loop` function in more detail (ideally as an edit to the question, e.g. list of bullet points)? To me the implementation is not completely clear, especially what is the purpose of `current_absolute_position` and why its first element is returned. I see you wrote *"For simplicity, all prices are quoted by the first asset (which price is always 1), [...]"* but I can't put that in perspective with the code.